# What species of Bear is Bosco and where was he found?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

On the avatar wikia I was trying to find some good information on Earth King Kuei's Pet Bear but couldn't find anything on the species of bear except...

> 1. Bosco is the last of his kind so far
> 2. Bosco does not act like a normal wild bear and Sokka was unsuccessful in teaching Bosco how to defend himself, roar ect....
> 3. The Earth King was looking for a mate for Bosco and sent a elite team of soldiers to scour the earth

But nothing about...

> 1. His species/Type of bear
> 2. Or where he was found

Is there anything in the comic book series or any other sources of information to hopefully answer this question.

Answers are wanted if you know!

Comment: He's just a bear.

Comment: Toph: "How about armadillo-bear?" Katara: "Nope. Just ... bear." Toph: "This place ... is weird."

Comment: I'd take a swing at grizzly bear, but if you're looking for the scientific binomial nomenclature (e.g. Homo sapien, Homo erectus etc) of the bear, well, I'd say you're thinking too hard. As for where he was found, there may be an answer out there ... but I can't help you with that! Sorry...

Comment: I guess so but I thought someone might know anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**That's the joke.**

When he's initially [described](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Transcript:City_of_Walls_and_Secrets) to Aang and Co as a "bear", they express their disbelief that he's not a "*[something]*-Bear", in line with many of the other uncommon animals mentioned in the series (scorpion-bee, hog-monkey, dolphin-piranha, otter-penguin, etc)

> **Katara :** The king is having a party tonight for his pet **bear**.
>
> **Aang :** You mean, platypus bear?
>
> **Katara :** No, it just says 'bear'.
>
> **Sokka :** Certainly you mean his pet skunk bear.
>
> **Toph :** Or his armadillo bear.
>
> **Aang :** Gopher bear?
>
> **Katara :** Just... bear.
>
> **Toph :** This place... is *weird*.

As to his exact species (and although it's not mentioned canonically in either the show or the scripts), his brown fur and whitened face would suggest that he's a Kodiak bear; ***Ursus Arctos Middendorffi*** also known as the Kodiak Brown Bear or the Alaskan Grizzly Bear

[image: Bosco Kodiak]

Comment: Finally a proper answer. Thanks Richard.

Comment: @oncer12_shawn - The best way to find yourself is to lose yourself in the service of others.

Answer (score 1):

### Perhaps the South Pole?

In the episode "Bato of the Water Tribe," we meet Bato (of the Water Tribe). His temporary set-up is decorated with many elements of the South Pole. On the ground, we see a rug made from the skin of a bear remarkably similar to Bosco.

[image]

Sokka exclaims that it's just like home, "even the pelts," while looking at the bear skin.